# Yum not discovering all package versions in repo

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, yum

When I check for available versions of `mysql-community-server` in Oracle's repo through the package manager, I only see the following:

```
# yum --showduplicates list mysql-community-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.hmc.edu
 * epel: mirror.hmc.edu
 * extras: centos.s.uw.edu
 * updates: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
Installed Packages
mysql-community-server.x86_64                                                 
8.0.11-1.el7                                                  
@mysql80-community
Available Packages
mysql-community-server.x86_64                                                 
8.0.11-1.el7                                                  mysql80-community
```

However, when I look in the actual repo at http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/el/7/x86_64/ , clearly 8.0.3 and 8.0.4 are in the repo. This prevents commands like `yum history undo` and `yum downgrade` from working. Why doesn't yum see the older versions of this package?

As a side note, the repo is enabled and I ran `yum clean metadata` before a subsequent retry.

Comment: yum only sees what's in the repo metadata. If not all the packages are in there then complain to the repo maintainer.

Comment: You are listing packages from `mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net` not from `repo.mysql.com` Perhaps you could add the `repo.mysql.com` to your list of repositories? Or you could just curl the RPM from the URL you listed and install manualls.